# Every map $G$ from $Y^* \to X^*$ can be expresed as $T^*$ where $T: X \to Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Suppose $X,Y$ are two normed spaces and let $X^*,Y^*$ denote their corresponding duals. We are given some bounded linear map $G: Y^* \to X^*$ and asked whether we can we find a corresponging bounded linear map $T:X \to Y$ such that $T^*=G$.

I guess the answer is no. I could not get that far into my argument, but I was thinking about the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are not finite dimensional, then their duals are strictly [bigger](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i). This suggests that the space of bounded linear functions between $X$ and $Y$ is of lower dimension than that of between $X^*$ and $Y^*$. I assume I need some additional argument that this is also true for the set of bounded linear functions between $Y^*$ and $X^*$.

Is there another approach you suggest? If not how can I close this argument? Thanks!

Comment: Given $G: Y^* -> X^*$ dualize it to get $G^* : X^{**} -> Y^{**}$. Now, $X$  is contained  in $X^{**}$  and $Y$ in $Y^{**}$ so, a natural candidate for $T$ would be $G^*$ restricted to $X$.

Comment: But we dont know that the image is in $Y$ right?